# How to update a table column using a loop of the previous SQL statment

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I hope I am asking the right question, but basically what I am trying to do is I have a SQL query that returns me a set of transaction times. which I would like to update another table using, however this needs to be in a loop format and I am wondering if this is doable via postgreSQL solely

I have a SQL statement that gives me the following set:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2014-02-24 19:39:15.746188
-[ RECORD 2 ]----+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2014-02-27 18:46:43.413777
-[ RECORD 3 ]----+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2014-02-27 20:10:02.400735
-[ RECORD 4 ]----+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2014-02-28 14:26:18.032892
-[ RECORD 5 ]----+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2014-03-04 17:51:51.366334
-[ RECORD 6 ]----+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2014-03-11 18:57:36.675897
-[ RECORD 7 ]----+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2014-03-12 20:22:32.393937
-[ RECORD 8 ]----+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2014-03-19 17:40:46.819432
-[ RECORD 9 ]----+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2014-03-25 16:21:17.876913
-[ RECORD 10 ]---+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2014-03-25 17:33:32.823483
-[ RECORD 11 ]---+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2014-03-26 15:19:34.420768
-[ RECORD 12 ]---+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2014-03-27 16:36:09.61764
-[ RECORD 13 ]---+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2014-03-31 16:39:32.38211
-[ RECORD 14 ]---+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2014-04-02 17:11:56.172384
-[ RECORD 15 ]---+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2015-01-13 18:39:50.743347
-[ RECORD 16 ]---+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2015-01-28 18:41:54.717222
-[ RECORD 17 ]---+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2015-01-31 15:54:42.56023
-[ RECORD 18 ]---+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2015-01-31 15:59:27.193869
-[ RECORD 19 ]---+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2015-01-31 16:04:37.272869
-[ RECORD 20 ]---+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2015-01-31 16:47:49.274627
-[ RECORD 21 ]---+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2015-02-02 23:23:00.687125
-[ RECORD 22 ]---+---------------------------
transaction_date | 2015-03-23 15:10:56.520156
```

So I can use the SQL from this query in the next one, hopefully.

I know that my usual update would look like:

```
UPDATE table SET status = 2,
                 transaction_date = x
WHERE master_id IN (398903,400926,504347,398895,398891,398950,
                    396673,385379,77545,122452,84203,94131,115898,
                    113037,78539,103786,77410,92518,112963,
                    126369,74213,114471)
```

I have the same amount of columns to update as what's in my first return so I am hoping maybe someone can shed some light on how I would be able to loop the results of the first query into my second one to make this update work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

-H

Comment: You say postgreSQL, but also tag MySQL. How come?

Comment: What is your first query? How do you get `master_id`, or otherwise form your `update` statement, from its results?

Comment: First query is just literally a fetch for transaction_dates. master_id is values I already know.